# Still cannot run unity on my laptop (nvidia optimus)?

Tags: 11.10, nvidia-optimus

When I had installed 11.04 due to my gpu's optimus technology, my laptop could not fully run unity.

I thought that with 11.10 release this would be covered.
When I run nvidia x server I see this message:

> You do not appear to be using the NVIDIA X driver...

But when I'm running Additional Drivers application I get this:

> This driver is activated and currently in use.

(Which did not happen before)

Additionally, after executing this command at the terminal I got this:

> /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
>   Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
>   Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
>   Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
>   Error: unable to create the OpenGL context

So what is wrong? :S

Thank you for your time.

Comment: check it ...i have a fix ...http://askubuntu.com/questions/164785/how-to-configure-bumblebee-in-ubuntu-12-04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bumblebee is a project that aim to deliver a complete experience for those who have a computer based on Nvidia Optimus https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee .

You can also find ppa, a.k.a. software just packed and ready to be installed, at  http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/06/bumblebee-gets-a-ppa-brings-nvidia-optimus-graphics-switching-to-ubuntu/ .

Comment: Yes, this was the solution to the problem when I had 11.04.
So it isn't fixed in 11.10?
Could I install gnome 3 with sudo apt-get install gnome-shell?

Comment: sounds like you are looking for a complete guide, i found this one that looks complete and well written http://www.ivegotavirus.com/blog/2011/11/06/how-to-get-optimus-working-on-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric/

Comment: thank you for the link! I will try it in a few hours. What if I want to undo the things I did at the guide? :S Also, by using bumblebee I will run any program I like using optirun programname. What if I don't want the program to run with bumblebee everytime?