# How To Configure Bumblebee In Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

After running `optirun firefox` i got the following error

```
Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_nvidia.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I google & found out the solution

```
ln -s /usr/lib/nvidia-current/vdpau/libvdpau_nvidia.so.1 /usr/lib/libvdpau_nvidia.so
```

**Now i m getting new error . How do i fix this error**

```
Xlib:  extension "NV-GLX" missing on display ":0".
```

**UpDate**

```
one@Ubuntu:~$ nvidia-settings -q NvidiaDriverVersion
one@Ubuntu:~$ nvidia-settings -q all
```

No output

Comment: Please edit your question to include the output of `nvidia-settings -q NvidiaDriverVersion`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solved

**The Solution**

```
nano /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf

# The Driver used by Bumblebee server. If this value is not set (or empty),
# auto-detection is performed. The available drivers are nvidia and nouveau
# (See also the driver-specific sections below)
Driver=   <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< edit
```

> ### Driver=nvidia

Then i did a reboot

```
optirun glxspheres   (at full screen)

OpenGL Renderer: GeForce GT 525M/PCIe/SSE2
187.070069 frames/sec - 190.120059 Mpixels/sec
187.936396 frames/sec - 191.000511 Mpixels/sec
186.800765 frames/sec - 189.846364 Mpixels/sec
187.095637 frames/sec - 190.146044 Mpixels/sec
188.431691 frames/sec - 191.503881 Mpixels/sec
188.418533 frames/sec - 191.490509 Mpixels/sec
187.152116 frames/sec - 190.203444 Mpixels/sec
189.413655 frames/sec - 192.501855 Mpixels/sec
187.145680 frames/sec - 190.196904 Mpixels/sec
186.200587 frames/sec - 189.236401 Mpixels/sec
189.276103 frames/sec - 192.362060 Mpixels/sec
187.059279 frames/sec - 190.109093 Mpixels/sec
186.445593 frames/sec - 189.485402 Mpixels/sec
188.927592 frames/sec - 192.007867 Mpixels/sec
```

> optirun firefox

**No error**

## Update

### librrfaker.so error & Xlib:  extension "NV-GLX" missing on display ":0".

**for 64 bit**

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librrfaker.so /usr/lib/
```

**for 32 bit**

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/librrfaker.so /usr/lib/
```

the last thing

```
sudo chmod u+s /usr/lib/librrfaker.so
```